# Check for additional blade file when laravel view() is executed

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have a project that is sharing much of the same functionality across multiple clients use, each with their own sub-domain to access and use. For each instance, I'd like to add the odd bit of additional formatting or information to some views and was hoping to check whether a file exists upon rendering the view.

For example:

Let's say I have three different instances of the product (so three subdomains) and when a user logs in they view `/dashboard` by default. If the view is rendered from `views/dashboard.blade.php`, I'd like to check whether there is a file called `views/subdomain.dashboard.blade.php` and if so, use that as the view instead. I'm thinking this may be possible using the View Composer but not entirely sure how as still getting up to speed with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper for that.

```
if (!function_exists('subdomain_view')) {
    function subdomain_view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        $subdomain = request()->route()->parameter('subdomain');
        $altView = "{$subdomain}.{$view}";

        return view(
            view()->exists($altView) ? $altView : $view,
            $data,
            $mergeData
        );
    }
}
```

It gets the subdomain, prefixes it to the view name, check if the prefixed view exists. If it does it uses that view, otherwise it uses the original view. It also uses the same signature as the `view()` helper.

Note that it makes use of the `request()` and and `view()` helpers without parameters. The default behavior of these helpers when called without parameters is to return the an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` and `Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory`, respectively.

Another way to make this work is to provide your own implementation of `Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface`. You can check the `Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder` class that implements this interface. You can just subclass from it and override the `find()` method. Then register the new class.

Update: You don't need to even subclass `FileViewFinder`, just tweak how `FileViewFinder` is registered inside the service provider. Other solutions include adding view namespaces. See [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-09-2014-how-do-you-change-the-view-path-without-changing-the-config-file).

Comment: I did consider this, however this means I would have to re-write the view() function anywhere it's called which is in thousands of places (I've been handed over the project). Would love a way to intercept the view() function directly.

Comment: I think you can implement your own finder class (implementing `Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface`).

Comment: @AdrianwithaW See my edit. I'll see if I can provide an example.